# Trying to query ContactList

Tags: android, android-contacts

Based on an earlier answer I got, I have this code within a BroadcastReceiver:

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(ASenderTel));
// Also tried;
//ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
//Context c = this;
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);
return (c.getCount() > 0);
```

...but get the err msg, "The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type KITSMSReceiver"

Comment: If I use:

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,
new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);


...the err msg is, "The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type KITSMSReceiver"

(KITSMSReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver)

Answer (score 2):

getContentResolver() is a method from android.content.Context class. You can access it from your activity for example. To achive it put broadcast receiver inside activity class:

quick draft:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  // ...

  private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
      MyActivity.this.recvBroadcast(i); // forward to your activity
      MyActivity.this.getContentResolver();  // <-----
    }
  }};

  // ...

}
```

Comment: That seems awfully convoluted; is that really the "preferred method"? And is a private BroadcastReceiver then visible to the event that should invoke it?

Comment: Actually you can use Context parameter that comes with onReceive method and put your BroadcastReceiver in separate file